# xfce, widgets gone, right-click (ctrl-click on mac) doesn't work

Tags: xfce

I installed xfce4 on an AWS EC2 instance and was able to use it through vnc on my Mac.  The xfce windows manager had some widgets I could use to do some simple things like start an xterm.  Something changed, all the widgets are gone, all that remains is a box in the center with 3 check fields

"Accept clipboard from viewers"
"Send clipboard to viewers"
"Send primary selection to viewers".

I uninstalled and reinstalled xfce4 on the AWS EC2 instance as an attempt to get the widges back.  No luck.  I googled on how to set widgets up and got instructions to start with right-click to get to menus.  But right-click (ctrl-click on my Mac) doesn't work.

Stuck.

Again, this was working before.  I may have inadvertently done something when I was trying to resize the windows manager, but I can't remember what.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  There were dangling vncserver procs out there with no vnc/*pid and vnc/*.log files.  Found them with ps, killed them, restarted vncserver and Voila!